# How to cite an Act of Parliament that varies by jurisdiction?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-citation

By way of example, the following is a citation using the [OSCOLA](https://www.law.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxlaw/oscola_4th_edn_hart_2012.pdf) style:

> Companies Act 2006, s 162(7)

However, that provision contains different text depending on whether the jurisdiction is Scotland (which relies on the original text of the Act) or England and Wales (which relies on amended text). I couldn't find anything in OSCOLA which deals with this situation.

My proposed solution is to write it as above for the case of Scotland, and for the case of England and Wales to write it with reference to the instrument which amended the text:

> Companies Act 2006, s 162(7) as amended by Legal Aid, Sentencing and
>   Punishment of Offenders Act 2012 (Fines on Summary Conviction)
>   Regulations 2015, sch 3 pt 1 para 9(5)

Does anyone know if my approach is correct? Answers don't have to be specific to OSCOLA; it's the general approach I am interested in rather than the specific citation style.

Answer (score 1):

I would cite it as:

> Companies Act 2006, s 162(7) as amended by Legal Aid, Sentencing and Punishment of Offenders Act 2012 (Fines on Summary Conviction) Regulations 2015, sch 3 pt 1 para 9(5)

if doing so is necessary to establish the relevant context for the reader.